# How can I make the first item in my *ngFor active by default?

Tags: arrays, angular, components, ngfor

I have a radio button component in Angular 2.

```
<div
    class="states"
    *ngFor="let state of states; let i = index"
    [ngClass]="{'selected': showElement === state}"
    (click)="trackCurrentState(state)">
    <div class="radio">
        <div class="outside">
            <div
                class="inside"
                *ngIf="showElement === state">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p2>{{state.name}}</p2>
</div>
```

The *ngFor loops through them and displays them inside of another component. On load my variable 'showElement' returns undefined until the user clicks one of the radio buttons. So on load I have a group of radio buttons, but none of them are selected until the user clicks one. I would like the first button in the group of radio buttons (the first item in the array of objects) to be selected by default. I need to apply my class 'inside' to just the first radio button until the user clicks another one. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I think you should have a name collision with "state", I saw as I tried to make a plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give "inside" class to the selected option you can simply use:

```
<div [class.inside]="showElement"> </div>
```

and to preselect an option:

```
 this.showElement = this.states[0];
```

in your constructor or on a ngOnInit, ngAfterViewInit - depending where you initialize this.showElement and this.states

Answer (score 1):

If I guess correctly what you need, it would be :

```
  this.showElement = this.states[0]
```